# Laravel sql server on mac

Tags: sql-server, macos, laravel, laravel-5, macos-sierra

So i installed SQL serve with docker on mac and i can actually manage to access my local sql server database with datagrip, but when i want to do a `php artisan migrate` i get this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)
```

and this error

```
[PDOException]could not find driver
```

i search for some answer but they where mostly for linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i manage to installed al the necessary drivers just by installing this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

php and Laravel worked perfectly after i installed those package and added this lines on my php.ini file:

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Comment: BTW you need to restart your machine

Answer (score 0):

You need a module called "pdo_mysql". Try `php_info()`to see if it's installed - I doubt it's there.

In your php.ini file (you can find it via `php --ini`) uncomment the line which has `extension=pdo_mysql.so` on it and restart the server.

edit: also make sure that the default key is set in your `config/database.php` file. Something like `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`

Comment: i'm getting this error when i uncomment my php.ini file  'PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.6_18/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.6_18/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0'

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: PHP 7.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2017 08:42:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Comment: It looks like you used brew to install php. Take a look at this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4011